# Получить токен страницы на facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Мне нужно получить json фаил со отзывами, о странице, сейчас моя ссылка выглядит так:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/204176960142772?access_token={$shorttime_token}&fields=id,name,ratings{reviewer,review_text,created_time,rating}
```

Мне не нужно брать информацию со страниц пользователей который попадает на мой сайт, мне нужно вывести инфу со странички на сайт. Возможно ли сделать всю инфу со странички доступной для любого токена? Или как получить токен чтобы он подходил к моей стр, но пользователю не приходилось логинится.

Я пробовал делать [вот так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315839/get-facebook-graph-api-page-review). но получил пустой масив при получении Page token (скорее всего из за недостаточных прав пользователя который залогинился).

```
stdClass Object
(
    [data] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Так же пробовал получать всю нужную инфу через [graph explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) там я получил нужный json

```
"data": [
  {
    "created_time": "2018-01-10T08:19:52+0000",
    "reviewer": {
      "name": "Jaroslav Nenarik",
      "id": "1273648189446584"
    },
    "rating": 5,
    "review_text": "Лучшее соотношение цена качество, парни стараются и очень ответственные. Все понравилось."
  }
],
"paging": {
  "cursors": {
    "before": "MTAwMDA0MDQyNDY0ODk4OjIwNDE3Njk2MDE0Mjc3MgZDZD",
    "after": "MTAwMDA0MDQyNDY0ODk4OjIwNDE3Njk2MDE0Mjc3MgZDZD"
  }
}
```

}

но токен который я использую в graph explorer работает короткое время.

Comment: ну наверное в апи почитать где он берется.

Comment: @Jean-Claude там показано как получить токен с апп id и сикретом, нет способа попроще что бы получить ревю страницы ? Насколько это правильно создавать приложение ради такой одноразовой задачи ?